# Unable to create process: Performing Streamed Install adb: failed to install

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

So I compiled my application for Android using target:
Android SDK 25.2.5 32 bit
I also have an emulator from Android Virtual Device Manager (AVD Manager) with CPU/ABI = Intel Atom (x86).
While I try to run my program from Delphi I get message:

```
Unable to create process: Performing Streamed Install adb: failed to install

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]
```

I read on a forum that I need Intel x86 in emulator because ARM emulation is too slow on a computer and that Delphi can only compile for ARM.

Is this true? There is no way to run .apk files from Delphi under x86 Android emulator?

Comment: It is true that Delphi compiles Android apps only to ARM, as most mobile devices use ARM CPUs.  On an x86 CPU, such as when running inside an emulator on an x86 PC, or running directly on an x86 device, you need the libHoudini library installed (most modern Android x86 systems nowadays have that preinstalled) so that ARM-compiled apps can be executed on the x86 CPU.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Will it run reasonably fast?

Comment: It depends on how good the performance of the ARM emulation is. Running Android on a PC emulator can be pretty slow in general. But yes, there is some overhead in running an ARM-compiled app inside of an x86 emulator/device.

Comment: ARM emulators are dog slow, that is why Google is pushing x86 emulators. I can only imagine that emulating ARM inside x86 emulator will be even worse. Of course, everything depends on how fast is your computer, but unless you don't have state of the art machine, it will be totally unusable - as in click on button and go fetch coffee unusable.